# MySQL SET UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, let's call them Pets and Owners. Both tables have a column called country_id, for whatever reason somewhere along the way there are Pets.Country_ID that are not equal to Owners.Country_ID (they should match).

In order to fix this I've run the following:

```
UPDATE pets
INNER JOIN owners ON owners.id = pets.owner_id
SET pets.country_id = IF(owners.country_id != pets.country_id, 
pets.country_id, owner.country_id)
WHERE pets.country_id != owners.country_id
```

Is this correct? I have run the query but I'm still getting mismatched results.

Comment: You should consider constraints that would not allow such mismatches.

Comment: @marekful this isn't the real data/table names obviously but there are cases where they can be mismatched but for now I'm just wanting to update them to be matched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your `if` clause, which is totally unnecessary, is wrong. Just remove it

```
UPDATE pets
INNER JOIN owners ON owners.id = pets.owner_id
SET pets.country_id = owners.country_id
WHERE pets.country_id != owners.country_id
```

Comment: Ran this, no rows affected.